# Lucene is getting slow when amount of terms is growing?

Tags: java, lucene

We have a Lucene index of 50Gb (4GB RAM on the machine). Searching with one term takes, say, 100ms. With two terms - 200ms, with three - 300ms, etc.

Is it an expected degradation of performance or we're doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by searching? Does that include sorting and retrieving the results?

Comment: I mean calling `org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher#search(query, collector)`. This particular call is taking longer when query contains more terms

Comment: Searching for a query of *k* distinct terms involves fetching the *k* postings lists corresponding to them, then computing the union of those. The linear increase in time shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: given how large your index is, you might get better performance by switching to a machine with more RAM or giving less memory to the JVM (if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for a query of *k* distinct terms involves fetching the *k* postings lists corresponding to them, then computing the union of those. In general, that will take linear time in the number of terms.